# What does ::-1 mean for python string index?

Tags: python, syntax

I was looking at python code that printed palindromes, and I stumbled upon this line of code:

`for i in range(1000, 7, -1):
    if (str(i) == str(i)[::-1])`

I'm trying to learn Python right now, and I'm just not that familiar with the syntax. Currently, I understand that this line of code checks to see if the first digit of integer i matches its last digit. Does the syntax of this line mean that the index is being incremented in order to check if it's a palindrome? What is the purpose of having two colons?

Answer (score 1):

The colons are separators. Rather than providing a "beginning" and an "end" index, it's telling Python to skip by every -1 objects in the array. It's effectively reversing the array.